# CSS -> _property:value is for IE+ or only until IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

For example

```
#div {
   _height: 300px;
}
```

What versions of IE will take this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore hack will only work in IE6. There was a variation of it that worked in IE7:

```
#div {
   *height: 300px;
}
```

But neither of these are recommended as they produce invalid CSS. It would probably be a far better idea to have separate CSS files and include them conditionally for different browsers:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For more information on conditional comments, see this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: thanks! that's what i'm tring to do; but i needed to detect if place it in ie.css or in ie6.css ;) thanks!

Comment: sorry if it's offtopic, but what about behavior? also only IE6?

Comment: If you're talking about the `behaviour` property, I think it works in IE6 and 7. After that, you can use `-ms-behaviour`.

Comment: US English spelling, by the way :P

Comment: @BoltClock - Oops, thanks! Well spotted. I'm just stuck in my British ways :)